# Use in opperator after lookup and unwind

Tags: mongodb

I used mondo db version 5.0.5
And faced with strange behaviour
I have query with lookup and unwind and afetr that need apply `$in` operator and look like I have wrong behaviour, I faced with data which don't have `fake_dta` in `device_tree_tbl.ancestors` property, any idea why ?

```
db.getCollection('metric').aggregate(
{
        $lookup: {
            from: "device_tree",
            localField: "pub_key_digest",
            foreignField: "node_id",
            as: "device_tree_tbl"
        }
    },
     {
         $unwind: {
             'path': '$device_tree_tbl'
             }
         },
       {
           $match: {
               'device_tree_tbl.ancestors': {$in: ['fake_dta']} 
               
               }
           
       }      
)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? NB, instead of `$unwind` and `$match` you may use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) - often it does the same but with better performance.

Comment: sorry, I found what it was, square brackets

Answer (score 1):

sorry about that, If someone faced with unexpected behaviour in aggregate query first of all need to check square brackets :)

works like needed

```
db.getCollection('metric').aggregate([

    {
        $match:
            { 'label': 'network', 'metric': 'rx_bytes' }

    },

{
        $lookup: {
            from: "device_tree",
            localField: "pub_key_digest",
            foreignField: "node_id",
            as: "device_tree_tbl"
        }
    },
     {
         $unwind: {
             'path': '$device_tree_tbl'
             }
         },
       {
           $match: {
               'device_tree_tbl.ancestors': {$in: ['1573394823429_4']} 
               
               }
           
           },
         
         
             {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$id"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    }
])
```